# Rails image_tag helper in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I use [this way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) of getting my methods inside my js, such as `current_user` etc. I need to get the `image_tag` inside my js. Why? I store the images inside the asset pipeline so once I upload to Heroku, it adds a weird string at the end of the image filename ie: `foo.png` becomes `foo-hkjghhgasb87ysbsb.png`.

**So inside an html.erb file:**

```
<div id="foo" data-editBtn="<%= image_tag("icons/ic_mode_edit_black_24px.svg", height: '24', width: '24') %>"></div>
```

**js.jsx file:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
{el.dataset.editBtn}
```

Is there a way to get the helper method to work in react or...how to add an image that is in the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'll answer this. Based on the [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) about images in the asset pipeline, I would:

**html.erb:**

```
<div id="foo" data-btn="<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>"></div>
```

**js.jsx:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo');
<div><img src={el.dataset.btn}></img></div>
```

No I got the image in the js with worrying about the generated finderprint.